# Why does my OpenGL program work with a 3.1 context, but not with 3.2 and above?

Tags: opengl, glfw

I have been following this starter guide to draw a triangle -

http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html

This thing is working properly as long as the opengl version is 3.1 or less (using glfwWindowHint). For 3.2 and higher, all i get is a black screen and there is no triangle.

I have made following modification in the shaders for 3.3 ->

```
static const char* vertex_shader_text =
"#version 330\n"
"uniform mat4 MVP;\n"
"layout(location = 1) in vec3 vCol;\n"
"layout(location = 0) in vec2 vPos;\n"
"out vec3 color;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vPos, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
"    color = vCol;\n"
"}\n";

static const char* fragment_shader_text =
"#version 330\n"
"in vec3 color;\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"    FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);\n"
"}\n";
```

There was no error as well. Can you please tell what i am doing wrong here?

**Note:** I am using glew.

**Note 2:** My GPU passed the rendering test of GLview for 3.2 and 3.3.

Comment: How did you set the OpenGL version of your context? Did you check it is the correct one? Did you check that the shaders compile successfully(using [`glGetShaderiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetShaderiv.xml))? Does your GPU support OpenGL 3.2+?

Comment: Opengl version has been set by using `glfwWindowHint`. I am not sure if thats the correct way. But, i have checked the opengl version of the current context (using `glGetIntegerv`) which was 3.3. What do you mean by "the return codes of glCompileShader"? There is no code and there was no error compiling the shader or linking the object. My GPU does support OpenGL 3.2+.

Comment: From the [documentation for `glCompileShader`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glCompileShader.xml): *"The compilation status will be stored as part of the shader object's state. [...] It can be queried by calling `glGetShaderiv` with arguments **shader** and `GL_COMPILE_STATUS`."*

Comment: I have checked that using `glGetShaderiv `, no error. Also no linking error. Checked with `glGetProgramiv`.

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov Are you using VAOs? IIRC they became mandatory in 3.3. Is that a Core or Compat context? I suggest you try asking for a Compat one first to see if that solves your problem. If it does, then you're doing something non-kosher in newer standard, and you'll just have to strip away pieces of your program until it starts working (or use a more intelligent method like a tracer or a debugger).

Answer (score 0):

The example referenced in the GLFW documentation is using the default Vertex Array Object (VAO) if Core Profile 3.2+ is used.  In [some driver implementations](https://hero.handmade.network/forums/code-discussion/t/896-opengl_vbo_without_vao), this means calls to `glVertexAttribPointer` will fail:

[OpenGL Core Profile](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf)

> The default vertex array object
>   (the name zero) is also deprecated. Calling VertexAttribPointer when no
>   buffer object or no vertex array object is bound will generate an INVALID_-
>   OPERATION error, as will calling any array drawing command when no vertex
>   array object is bound.

One approach to using a VAO in 3.2+ Core Profiles is to create and use a single VAO instance that replaces the "name zero" default VAO:

```
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// proceed as normal
```

It's a good idea to delete the VAO on cleanup with `glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);`.  More information about Vertex Array Objects can be found [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object).